# SQL Server - SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() returns identical values even with an added delay

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to understand some odd behavior in SQL Server. I've seen it in SQL Server 2019 and in Azure SQL Server.

The gist of it is that I get the same value from the SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() function when I call it consecutively, even if I put a delay of several milliseconds between calls.

The behavior is intermittent, so I placed the code in a loop to try it repeatedly. On Azure SQL I have been able to reproduce it with a delay of up to 14 ms (tried 15 milliseconds but haven't reproduced it with that even after running the loop for ten minutes). On SQL Server 2019, I have reproduced it with a delay of 1ms (2ms seems to not produce the issue). I am thinking either WAITFOR is doing no delay, or SYSDATETIMEOFFSET is reporting a wrong value. I also tested with the SYSUTCDATETIME() function, but that didn't change the results.

Can anyone explain this odd behavior?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @DelayString VARCHAR(100) = '00:00:00.014';
DECLARE @UseSysDateTimeOffset BIT = 1;

DECLARE @D1 DATETIMEOFFSET;
DECLARE @D2 DATETIMEOFFSET;
DECLARE @DateDifference TIME = '00:01'; --initalize to large value so it enters loop
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 0;
WHILE @DateDifference > CONVERT(TIME, '00:00:00.0000000')
BEGIN
    IF @UseSysDateTimeOffset = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @D1 = (SYSUTCDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
        WAITFOR DELAY @DelayString;
        SELECT @D2 = (SYSUTCDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @D1 = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET();
        WAITFOR DELAY @DelayString;
        SELECT @D2 = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET();
    END
            
    SELECT @DateDifference = TIMEFROMPARTS(0,0,0, DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @D1, @D2), 3);
    SET @LoopCounter += 1;
END

SELECT @D1 AS D1, @D2 AS D2,  @DateDifference AS DateDifference, @LoopCounter AS LoopCounter, @DelayString AS DelayString;
```

Comment: It's probably dependent on whether the High Resolution Timer is enabled, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps and Windows is not a real-time operating system so you can't do precise `WAITFOR` timers anyway

Comment: Is there any way I could prove this false? If I wrote a client application to test this out, had it perform the same set of queries (send a "SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()", do a Thread.Sleep or Task.Delay, query the date a second time), and replicated the issue...would the answer be the same?

Comment: Instead of calling out to SQL Server, test with a simple `Stopwatch` and `Thread.Sleep` in C#